# Are the random variables $X$ and $Y$ independent given the law of $(X,Y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, marginal-distribution

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector whose density $f$  is given as follows:
$$f(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\pi}\exp\left(\frac{-1}{2}(4x^2+2xy+y^2)\right)$$
$\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2.$

With this information, I determined the density of $X$ and $Y.$ 
$$f_X(x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{3x^2}{2}\right)$$
and 
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{3y^2}{8}\right).$$
I see that $f(0,0)\neq f_X(0)f_Y(0)$, but I am not sure whether this is enough to conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

Comment: If $f(x,y)\ne f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ for at least one $(x,y)$, then that proves $X$ and $Y$ are *not* independent.

Comment: @StubbornAtom The quadratic form in the exponent can be orthogonally diagonalized.  This allows an *unusual* change in coordinates (rotation) so that the quadratic form becomes a sum of scalar multiple of two squares.  As a result, the density will become a product of two marginal densities.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f_{X,Y} (x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.